# Checking Conditional Probability on Discrete Random Variable

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, measurable-functions

Let $Y: \left( \Omega, \Sigma \right)  \rightarrow ( \mathbb{R}, \mathrm{Borel})$ be a *discrete* random variable. I would like to check whether
\begin{align}
P(A | Y) = \sum_i 1_{Y = y_i} P(A | Y = y_i)
\end{align}
holds. I.e. I want to show that for all $B$ that lie in the sigma algebra generated by $Y$, we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} \left( P(A | Y ) 1_B \right) = P(A \cap B).
\end{align}
How would I go about that?

Comment: \begin{align}
\mathbb{E} \left( P(A | Y ) 1_B \right) = P(A \cap B).
\end{align} for $B \in \sigma(Y)$ by definition of conditional expectation.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Indeed, hence I would like to check whether my formula for $P(A|Y)$ really satisfies *this* definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the right side of your first equation as an alternative definition of the left, you have
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(P(A|Y)1_B)&=\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_i1_B1_{Y=y_i}P\big(A|Y=y_i\big)\right)\\
&=\sum_i\mathbb{E}\big(1_{B\cap\{Y=y_i\}}\big)P\big(A|Y=y_i\big)\\
&=\sum_iP\big(B\,\cap\{Y=y_i\}\big)\frac{P\big(A\cap\{Y=y_i\}\big)}{P\big(Y=y_i\big)}\\
&=\sum_{i:y_i\in Y(B)}P\big(A\,\cap\{Y=y_i\}\big)\\
&=P(A\cap B)\ .
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks a lot! The penultimate equation leaves out the $\sum_{i : y_i \notin Y(B)}$ term which is zero actually.

Comment: By the way, do you have an idea why $B$ belonging to the sigma algebra generated by $Y$ seems to be an unnecessary statement in this context?

Comment: It isn't unnecessary.  Unless $\ B\ $ is of the form $$\ B=\bigcup_\limits{i\in S}Y^{-1}\big(\{y_i\}\big)\ ,$$ the last two of the chain of identities won't necessarily hold.

Comment: So, in the final step, we use sigma additivity and the fact that
\begin{align}
B = \bigcup_{i : y_i \in Y(B)} \{ Y = y_i \}.
\end{align}
How does this relate to the fact that $B$ lies in the sigma algebra generated by $Y$?

Comment: A set $\ B\ $ is in the $\ \sigma$-algebra generated by $\ Y\ $ if and only if $\ B=Y^{-1}(R)\ $ for some Borel subset $\ R\ $ of $\ \mathbb{R}\ $. But if $\ Y\ $ is discrete, then
$$
Y^{-1}(R)=\bigcup_{i\in S}Y^{-1}\big(\{y_i\}\big)\ ,
$$
where $\ S=\{\,i\,|\,y_i\in R\,\}\ $, so $\ B\ $ is in the $\ \sigma$-algebra generated by $\ Y\ $ if and only if it has the form of the right-hand-side of the above identity.

Comment: However, *not all sets in* $\ \Sigma\ $ are *necessarily* of this form. And if $\ B\in\Sigma\ $ but $\ B\ $ *isn't* in the the $\ \sigma$-algebra generated by $\ Y\ $, then $\ B\ $ *won't* have that form, and the last two identities in the chain of identities I gave in my answer won't necessarily hold.  Of course, *if* $\ \Sigma\ $ were the $\ \sigma$-algebra generated by $\ Y\ $, then it would then be unnecessary to specify that $\ B\ $ belonged to that $\ \sigma$-algebra because of an implied understanding that $\ B\in\Sigma\ $.

Comment: However it was not specified in your question that $\ \Sigma\ $ is the $\ \sigma$-algebra generated by $\ Y\ $.